# Is this working well without putting return in the redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my project, I'm using redux-thunk to deal with the asynchronous function. 
The regular way to write the function is as follow,

```
return (dispatch) => {
   return fetchAPI().then(doSomething)
}
```

But I have a question about if there's no 'return' before the fetchAPI function. Will this make any side effects for the program?

```
return (dispatch) => {
  fetchAPI().then(doSomething)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `fetchAPI().then(doSomething)` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you might want to use it for checking its status, for example, if you want to indicate a `loading` state somewhere.

If you don't use the value it won't introduce side any effects.

Answer (score 0):

> But I have a question about if there's no 'return' before the fetchAPI function. Will this make any side effects for the program?

As I understand, no side effects will be created.

---

Looking at the video [Redux Thunk Tricks](https://youtu.be/xihoZZU0gao).

I understood that you may want to return the promise from the action if you want to dispatch another action after promise resolved.

Suppose I want to dispatch `actionWithPostId` after `actionFetchPosts` succeeded.

```js
function actionFetchPosts() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetchAPI().then(doSomething)
  }
}

function actionWithPostId(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: "POST_ID", payload: id})
  }
}

...

actionFetchPosts()
  .then(posts => actionWithPostId(posts[0].id));
```